# remove prepositions url or not?

Tags: seo, friendly-url

I have a website with urls are like:

```
barack-obama-at-a-restaurant-in-ny
```

I noticed some websites write URLs like this:

```
barack-obama-restaurant-ny
```

removing prepositions and link words. Is it better for SEO?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely shorter link URL which is meaningfull for the search engine crawlers, makes your SEO better. Generally shortening of long phrases in title, URL, Description and etc can help the crawlers catch better and easier concepts.

Regards